# Android - Firebase Cloud Messaging Device to Device Push Notification Without Server

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there a way to send push notification between 2 android devices without a server?

I found some tutorials but all of them was using the node.js for sending a notification. (Or I found that some samples that were using the firebase console for doing this)

Answer (score 1):

Nope,

You need a "server" to do push notification. You can use a variety of services to do that, as you mentioned firebase is one of them. You may not need a full on server, but you need some kind of service to do that, you can't simply send notifications between devices straight away:

Some examples are:

[AWS Serverless functions](https://github.com/georgelovegrove/expo-serverless-push-notifications)

[Cloud functions in firebase](https://android.jlelse.eu/cloud-functions-for-firebase-device-to-device-push-notification-f4c548fd9b7d)

If you'd rather use one of these services, then you'll need to configure FCM in your app, you can check how to do that in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client?hl=pt-br). And some nice sample codes [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging) :)