# Flutter Push notification to iOS & Android without firebase?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, push-notification, notifications

I wonder how to push notifications to my Flutter app users in both Android and iOS devices **Without** using any external service like Firebase or OneSignal?

I want to implement a code in **PHP** which can send push real time notifications to all/spesific users in my **Flutter app** which works in both Android and iOS.

I found some solutions like [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications/) with [workmanger](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager) which can fetch the API in the background only minimum 15 minuts. [Workmanger](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager) is Not good solution because its work only during 15 min and it will consume the battery and internet.

I need an efficient solution to my flutter app for both Android & iOS devices, which can listen on real time to the coming messages from the server even when the app is closed.

How to fix that? thanks

Comment: I dont think that there is any working example in the past, here is another question with the same which is the same subject https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55557389/how-to-setup-push-notifications-with-flutter-without-firebase-and-with-own-custo 
You can either try to work with the work manager or have to use Firebase.

Comment: The problem is my backend is build in PHP and I cannot send information to external services because GDPR and Security. ThusI need another solution. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: i have the same problem @M123

Comment: do you have a solution for this ? @mike

Comment: @lucky No, I did not find any solution yet.

Comment: @mike Why you think 15 minutes interval will consume a battery and the internet? It will make 96 requests everyday.

Comment: @mike, on iOS when the app is closed you can use a silent push notification (via Apple's Push Notification Server) to wake up the app. This gives the app 30seconds to perform necessary API calls etc in the background.

As far as I'm aware, your iOS app will not be able to receive "real time" messages from your own server once put in the background.

I'm unable to comment on Android apps.

Answer (score 1):

### iOS

You will *always* need to integrate with Apple's Push Notification Server (APNS) if your app needs make API calls in the background. The reason is that once an app is put into the background, iOS will often put the app to sleep soon afterwards.

The correct approach to this is to use a silent push notification to *wake up* the app. When received, no message is shown on device but the app get's about 30 seconds in order to make API calls.

In your case, the app can make the API call and then schedule a *local push notification* to display your message.

[Background updates via push notifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app)

[Scheduling local push notifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/scheduling_a_notification_locally_from_your_app)

### Android

It looks like WorkManager is your best bet. I don't see how it can affect battery.

#### FYI

You don't need to use Firebase or OneSignal for push notifications, silent or otherwise. They are simply 3rd party services that interact with the official Apple or Google Push Notification Servers.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I think this is not possible. Even OneSignal uses the Firebase API to deliver the notifications, as you can see [here](https://onesignal.com/blog/firebase-vs-onesignal/). For all other solutions, you will have to balance the update frequency with internet use and battery consumption.